# Extending the logical OR || syntax for the empty array

Tags: javascript

Let `f` and `g` be two function. Then `f() || g()` first evaluates `f`. If the return value of `f` is falsy it then evaluates `g`, and returns `g`'s return value.

I love the neat and concise syntax, but it doesn't include the case where `f` returns the empty array `[]`, which I want to consider "falsy".

Is there clean way of having this syntax for `[]` instead of the traditional falsy values?

Comment: `[]` is an empty array, `{}` is an empty object. Which do you want to consider falsy? Or is it both?

Comment: Sorry, empty array `[]`. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Also more info about the function f would be useful. For example, if it always returns an array you could do `f().length || g()`. Which will execute g if the length of the array is falsy (0 elements)

Comment: The function `f` can return anything. But your solution if `f` only returns arrays is cute!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a function that converts the empty array into a real falsy value, maybe?

```
function e(a) { return a instanceof Array ? (a.length ? a : false) : a; }

var result = e(f()) || g();
```

Comment: Except you need to change your `e` function That will return falsy for any truthy non-array (or anything without a length property). Change it to: `function e(a) { return typeof a.length === 'number' && !a.length ? false : a; }`

Comment: Nice Edit. Even better than my suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the other solutions presented is that it doesn't behave exactly how you may want the short-circuiting to work. For example, converting the value of `f()` to a truthy value before the `||` operator means you lose the ability of returning the result of `f()`. So here's my preferred solution: write a function that behaves like the `||` operator.

```
// let's call the function "either" so that we can read it as "either f or g"
function either () {
    var item;
    // return the first non-empty truthy value or continue:
    for (var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++) {
        item = arguments[i];
        if (item.length === 0 || !item) continue
        return item;
    }
    return false;
}
```

We can now use the `either()` function like how we would the `||` operator:

```
either(f(), g());
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply do the length check at `f()`?

```
function f(){
  var returned_array = new Array();
  ...
  if(!returned_array.length)
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about actually overloading the || operator, you cannot do that in JavaScript (it was [proposed back in ECMAScript 4](https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=pFIHldY_CkszsFxMkQOReAQ&gid=2) but rejected). If you really want to do operator overloading in JavaScript, you'd have to use something like [JavaScript Shaper](http://jsshaper.org/), which is "an extensible framework for JavaScript syntax tree shaping" - you could actually [use this to overload operators](http://nixtu.blogspot.com/2011/05/using-jsshaper-to-provide-operator.html).